# I need to learn how to convert regular time and date format into unix time format

Tags: time

I am trying to edit a URL on google locatiion history.  I need to know how to enter february 15 2013 in unix time format (the 10 digit format) I'm not a computer whiz so if anyone can just give me the answer and not try to teach me how right now I'd really appreciate that. If you have any suggestions on any websites I can go to and learn how later on or any suggestions on android apps that convert regular time into unix time please tell me!

Comment: -1 because you could have solved this easily by googling.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of online tools that can do that; a simple Google search for 'convert to unix time' yields a lot of results, epochconverter.com being just one. If you want to do it programmatically, I recommend php's mktime() .

Answer (score 2):

- URL: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=february+15+2013+in+unix+time
- command line: `date -d "2013-02-15" +%s`

If you want to learn how a Unix timestamp is calculated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: That assumes GNU date.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime -r %Y-%m-%d 2013-02-15
1360886400
$ strftime -r '%b %d %Y' 'february 15 2013'
1360886400
```

With `ksh93`:

```
$ printf '%(%s)T\n' '2013-02-15 00:00:00'
1360886400
$ printf '%(%s)T\n' 'february 15 2013 00:00'
1360886400
```

With GNU `date`:

```
$ date -d 'february 15 2013' +%s
1360886400
```

(Note that you may get a different result in your timezone).