# convert timestamp to epoch with bash builtin printf

Tags: bash, date, printf

While researching a different approach to convert a timestamp like

> 2015-09-08 11:07:35

to

> 1441703255

I found a lot of pretty commonly found solutions use e.g.

```
date +%s --date "2015-09-08 11:07:35"
```

awk, perl or similiar solutions.

However [SE conversion answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804450/1081936) seems to use `printf` for that conversion on a "newer" bash version.

As this is to be used in a script with some limitations I rather not have to rely on `date` for that, but instead try an approach which might be faster.
My relevant tries so far:

```
printf '%(%s)2015-09-08 11:07:35'
bash: printf: warning: `2': invalid time format specification

printf '%(%s)T' "2015-09-08 11:07:35"
bash: printf: 2015-09-08 11:07:35: invalid number
```

It seems I am unable to correctly use `printf` as I lack the exact manual where the dateformat string is described. 
The manpage and  `info coreutils 'printf invocation'` did not help me solve this issue.

bash version is

```
bash --version
GNU bash, Version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: @don_crissti may as well make an answer out of that.

Comment: @don_crissti thank you for confirming, i was afraid it is like that, please add this as answer, i will accept this after a day or so, if noone prooves us all wrong.

Comment: `printf '%(%s)T' "2015-09-08 11:07:35"` works in ksh93, not bash. If you want a shell with strptime capability, [your options are ksh93 and zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91148/22565).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other question specifically asks how to "get *current* time in seconds since the Epoch". The date format and arguments are described in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) (scroll down to `printf`):

> ```
> %(datefmt)T
> ```
>
> Causes `printf` to output the date-time string resulting from using *datefmt* as a format string for `strftime`(3). The corresponding *argument*
>   is an integer representing the number of seconds since the epoch. Two
>   special argument values may be used: `-1` represents the current time,
>   and `-2` represents the time the shell was invoked. If no argument is
>   specified, conversion behaves as if `-1` had been given. This is an
>   exception to the usual `printf` behavior.

So the argument has to be an integer number of seconds since epoch¹ (e.g. see the [answer to "How do I convert an epoch timestamp to a human readable format"](/a/219554)).

---

¹ Unless you use the special values (`-1` or `-2`) or no argument (and in that case it defaults to `-1`)